# Need help in solving defined integral problem.

Tags: definite-integrals

The graph of the continuous function $y = f (x)$ is symmetric with respect to the origin, for all real numbers $x$

If $$ f(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}\int_1^{x+1}f(t)dt$$ and $f(1)=1$

Find $$\pi^2\int_0^1xf(x+1)dx$$ 
I have tried:$$f'(x)=\frac{\pi}{2}f(x+1)$$  and as the function is odd $f(-1)=-1$ $$\frac{\pi}{2}\int_0^1f(x+1)dx=1$$
But I can`t go any further can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From given condition,
$$f(0) = 0, \ \ f'(x) = \frac{\pi}{2}f(x+1), \ \ f'(x-1) = \frac{\pi}{2}f(x) $$

Then,

$$\begin{align}\pi^2\int_{0}^{1}xf(x+1)dx &= 2\pi\int_{0}^{1}xf'(x)dx \\\\
&= 2\pi(xf(x)|_{0}^{1} - \int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx) \\\\
&= 2\pi - 4\int_{0}^{1}f'(x-1)dx \\\\
&= 2\pi - 4f(x-1)|_{0}^{1} \\\\
&= 2\pi + 4f(-1) \\\\
&= 2\pi-4 \end{align}$$

Comment: This is being very helpful but can you clarify how you changed f(x) in the defined integral from o to 1 in the third line to  4 times defined integral from 0 to 1  of f '(x-1)

Comment: $f'(x-1) = \frac{\pi}{2}f(x)$

Comment: @R.Temur Did you understand?

Comment: from where f′(x−1)=π/2f(x) was taken or found

Comment: how to find it , please help

Comment: Replace $x$ by $x-1$ in the given equation and then take derivative wrt $x$. Got it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62445/discussion-between-r-temur-and-expittp1z0).